# FhirClient.CreateAsync returning null instead of OperationOutcome

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have setup a `FhirClient` to create a new resource.

```
var clientSettings = FhirClientSettings.CreateDefault();
clientSettings.PreferredReturn = Prefer.OperationOutcome;

var uri = $"https://psims-uat.azure-api.net/adverse-event/fhir";
var fhirClient = new FhirClient(uri, clientSettings, _handler);
return await fhirClient.CreateAsync<AdverseEvent>(adverseEvent);
```

The code is returning null, instead I want an `OperationOutcome` so I can extract any warnings and the created resource Id.

Where have I gone wrong?

---

For completeness `_handler` is providing my subscription key, as follows:

```
public class SubscriptionKeyHeaderHandler : HttpClientHandler 
{
    private readonly string subKey;
    private readonly string fhirVersion;

    public SubscriptionKeyHeaderHandler(string subKey, string fhirVersion ) : base()
    {
        this.subKey = subKey;
        this.fhirVersion = fhirVersion;
    }

    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subKey);
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.Headers.Add("fhir-version", fhirVersion);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: My kingdom for PackageReference (and version values) and "using" (or in another world "import") statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FhirClient can only return a resource of the type you create, or null, or throw an exception when an error was returned. So the null you get is actually expected in this case, since there is no `AdverseEvent` resource and the request was successful.

What you can do to inspect the `OperationOutcome`, is look at the `fhirClient.LastBodyAsResource`. The resource's technical id will also be in the response headers, so that information can be found through `fhirClient.LastResult.Location`.

Comment: I'm confused why there isn't a resource created in the FhirClient when there appears to be one created by Postman for the same message?

Comment: The CreateAsync returns the type of resource that you send in, or null if there is no resource of that same type in the response. So yes, there is an OperationOutcome in the response, but it is not an AdverseEvent. For the CreateAsync<AdverseEvent> the return type is AdverseEvent. Since there is none, null is returned. The client does retain the response, so if there's another type in the response, you can take a look at that with the extra steps.